# Container output directory not visible in Host

Tags: docker

I have Dockerfile as shown here. 
A script in the entrypoint creates a directory and places few artifacts.

```
# from base image
FROM ......

RUN mkdir -p /home/myuser

RUN groupadd -g 999 myuser &&\
    useradd -r -u 999 -g myuser myuser

ENV HOME=/home/myuser
ENV APP_HOME=/home/myuser/workspace


RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN chown -R myuser:myuser $APP_HOME

USER myuser

ENTRYPOINT ......
```

I start a container for the above image as shown here

```
sudo docker run -v ${WORKSPACE}/output:/home/myuser/workspace/output image
```

I could not get the artifacts in the host machine. `${WORKSPACE}/output` created with permission `drwxr_xr_x`

What is the process to get the container files into the host machine?

**Additional Info:**

- My host username is `kit`
- container user is `myuser`
- container works perfectly fine - at the time of creating output file it throws an error that `Permission denied`
- I tried to give full permission `drwxrwxrwx` to `${WORKSPACE}/output`. then i could see the output files.

Comment: Is the container running correctly?

Comment: The output dir is empty?

Comment: yes it  is empty

Comment: Are the files in home/myuser/workspace/output in your container when you use docker exec

Comment: Also, container works fine. while writing into output directory, it throws an error that permission denied

Comment: What uid owns the directory on the host? Use `id -u` to lookup your current user uid.

Comment: it shows 1000  .

Comment: Did you try to chown the dir in the Dockerfile with the user with which you are running your container?

Answer (score 0):

The permission denied error is because you are running a container with uid 999, but trying to write to a host directory that is owned by uid 1000 and only configured to allow writes by the user. You can:

- chmod the directory to allow anyone to write (not recommended, but quick and easy)
- update your image to match the uid/gid of your user on the host
- switch to using a named volume
- use an entrypoint to align the container uid/gid to that of a volume mount before starting your app

I go into a bit more detail on these in [my slides here](https://rawgit.com/sudo-bmitch/dc2018/master/faq-stackoverflow-lightning.html#41). There are also some speaker notes in there (I believe either P or S will bring them up).